# Postgres insert strings with null between the characters

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, varchar

I got a table where the data may contain null between the characters. As I have already defined the table as VARCHAR, it throws me an error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for
>   encoding "UTF8": 0x00

There should be a way where I can insert a null based string in postgres.
This is the sample insert that has failed while inserting onto postgres

```
private void postGrestest() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    String dropStmt = "DROP TABLE PUBLIC.TEST";
    String createStmt = "CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.TEST(COL1 VARCHAR(50), COL2 BOOLEAN)";
    String insertStmt = "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.TEST VALUES (?, ?)";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/objectserver?stringtype=unspecified",
            "username", "password");
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertStmt);)
    {
        stmt.execute(dropStmt);
        stmt.execute(createStmt);
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Object str = "Test" + i;
            str = ((String) str).replace('s', '\0');
            logger.info("Inserting " + str);
            // str = ((String) str).replace("\0", "");
            ps.setObject(1, str);
            Object obj = String.valueOf(r.nextBoolean());
            ps.setObject(2, obj);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any considerations before dealing with this type of data? This data is a string based one where the source may contain data containing null between them. This is handled well on a different database instance SQL Server using NVARCHAR.

Answer (score 2):

You can't include a null in a string in PostgreSQL. From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE):

> The character with the code zero cannot be in a string constant.

Java uses a slightly [modified Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) scheme where `U+0000` can be encoded as `0xC0 0x80`, a two-byte encoding. You might replace these values in the string rather than a binary null. PostgreSQL will gladly ingest it.

Comment: I understand. Can this be replaced on the backend with any other delimiter or a codepoint that will not be used?

Comment: Replacing \0 with \uC080 does not help as it represents 삀. It writes as 'Te삀t0'. I wanted the backend user to run the query where it should not be represented in the table. Will WIN1252 be helpful in this case?

Comment: In utf-8 U+C080 expands to 0xEC 0x82 0x80. You should not insert that code point directly but just the two bytes that make up the code point.